# Syntax Questions in "You don’t have a clue where your money is."

Tags: negative-polarity-items

In the captioned sentence:

> You don’t have a clue where your money is.

If "where your money is" is a nominal clause, what is its relationship to "clue"?

I am thinking maybe the nominal clause is an adjectival clause, acting as an adjective predicative to the noun "clue".

Comment: _Have a clue_ is a negative-polarity idiom that is equivalent to _know, be aware_. As such, it has many of the same affordances as _know_, including the ability to take a _wh_-clause complement. I.e, the sentence means "You don't know where your money is", and the _wh_-clause is clearly the direct object of _know_.

Comment: The word *clueless* has a meaning that is related to this idiom — when applied to a person, it means *uninformed*, *ignorant*, *confused*, or even *stupid*.

Comment: "Where your money is" is the type of clue you don't have.

Comment: And the wh-clause is also called an embedded question.

Comment: @GregLee - Except that that terminology is misleading -- there is no question.

Comment: @Scott -- If Sherlock Holmes is "clueless" that doesn't mean he's any of those things.  Nor does not having a clue about the whereabouts of your money imply any of those things -- it may simply be you had your accounts with Wells Fargo.

Answer (score 1):

> *Have a clue* is a negative-polarity idiom that is equivalent to know, be aware. As such, it has many of the same affordances as know, including the ability to take a *wh*-clause complement. I.e, the sentence means "You don't know where your money is", and the *wh*-clause is clearly the direct object of know. – John Lawler